# not available Gem::SafeYAML when to run 'bundle install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to run **bundle install** from the project, I get the following error:

```
unavalible Gem :: SafeYAML when to run 'bundle install'
```

my version of rubygem is:
**2.0.14**

Comment: post your Gemfile here

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.7.1'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5.4'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'httparty'
gem 'sendgrid-actionmailer'
gem 'hubspot-ruby', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'spring'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'htmlcompressor', '~> 0.4.0'

Answer (score 0):

After investigating what I could solve with the following steps:

1.-Download the zip file from the following [download](https://rubygems.org/pages/download?locale=es#formats) and add it to the root of the project

2.- If you don't have any RubyGems installed, there is still the pre-gem approach to getting software, doing it manually:

2.1-Download from above
2.2-Unpack into a directory and cd there
2.3-Install with: `ruby setup.rb` (you may need admin/root privilege)

2.4- like sudo:
    gem update --system
3. run:

```
bundle install
```